# TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list (python)

Tags: python

I am a student self teaching myself python programming. Because of this I have a limited knowledge of python or programming in general. If you can please try to make it simple although anything  is appreciated.

This is my code which seems to have a problem:

```
#starting question
option_select = str(input("Please tell us your problem ,"))

#list of keywords
phone_not_turning_on = ['black']
audio_problem = ['distorted'] ,['quiet']

#phone not turning on
if any(word in option_select for word in phone_not_turning_on):
      print ("Not turning on")

#audio problem
if any(word in option_select for word in audio_problem):
      audio_responce = str(input("input troubleshoot thing here"))
```

Also if you have any additional tips i will be great full

Thankyou, and have a nice day

Comment: Your `audio_problem` variable is a tuple of lists. I believe this might be a better solution: `audio_problem = ['distorted', 'quiet']` That way you only have one list.

Comment: Could you please provide the entire traceback? And are you using python 2 or 3?  If python 3 the calls to `str()` to the return value of `input()` is redundant.